# When using the (64-Bit) Selenium Internet Explorer Driver, will it use the version of IE on the User's PC?

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automated-tests

How do I know what version of IE is, when testing with the Selenium (64-Bit) 'Internet Explorer Driver'?

Comment: Please provide more details in the question

Comment: No problem.  When starting a Selenium WebDriver (i.e. either 'FireFox', 'Chrome' or 'IE'), does the WebDriver use the 'installed Browser Version' (live IE Version 10 or 11) on the Laptop or PC?  Or does the WebDriver has it's own browser version independent of what is installed on the PC/Laptop?  

Does this make sense?

Comment: It will use the one that's installed on the machine you are running tests against. I guess, using a Selenium Grid you can control which version to run against. Taka a look at DesiredCapabilities class. It should be sth like: driver.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "internet explorer");
driver.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "8");